# golang Kafka consumer 100% CPU usage without messages

Tags: go, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a straightforward kafka consumer with a worker pool:

```
type Worker struct {
    consumer *Consumer
    events   chan *kafka.Message
}

func (w *Worker) start() {
    for event := range w.events {
        w.consumer.handledEventMap[callBackKey] += 1
        w.consumer.HandleMessage(event)
    }
}

type WorkerPool struct {
    workers []*Worker
    queue   chan *kafka.Message
}

func NewWorkerPool(consumer *Consumer, numWorkers int) *WorkerPool {
    pool := &WorkerPool{
        workers: make([]*Worker, numWorkers),
        queue:   make(chan *kafka.Message),
    }

    for i := 0; i < numWorkers; i++ {
        pool.workers[i] = &Worker{
            consumer: consumer,
            events:   pool.queue,
        }
        go pool.workers[i].start()
    }

    return pool
}

func (pool *WorkerPool) Stop() {
    close(pool.queue)
}
```

with my kafka consume method:

```
func (c *Consumer) Consume() {
    numWorkers := 10
    pool := NewWorkerPool(c, numWorkers)
    defer pool.Stop()
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 60)

    for {
        select {
        case event := <-c.consumer.Events():
            switch e := event.(type) {
            case *kafka.Message:
                pool.queue <- e // Add the event to the worker pool's queue
            case kafka.Error:
                logrus.WithError(e).Warning("an error occurred while reading from topic")
            }
        case <-ticker.C:
            logrus.Infof("Consumer %s received events in past 60 seconds: %v", c.consumerName, c.handledEventMap)
            c.handledEventMap = make(map[string]int)
        }

}
```

where this code runs in a container. Straight off the bat, each container that runs this code consumes +- 100% CPU, without any messages. I am using the default configuration for the kafka consumer with `confluent-kafka-go` as my library. I am expecting thousands of messages per second per container.

What am I doing wrong? I thought the worker pool will solve my issue but it didn't change anything.
Thanks

Comment: Please show more information about `c.consumer.Events()`. If it returns a closed channel, `<-c.consumer.Events()` proceed immediately. If you see a lot of `an error occurred while reading from topic`, then this could be the reason.

Comment: @ZekeLu its the kafka consumer event channel: https://rmoff.net/2020/07/14/learning-golang-some-rough-notes-s02e03-kafka-go-consumer-channel-based/ , i'm not getting errors, channel is definitely opened. just 100% CPU

Comment: I think your loop is in a continuous operation of checking the Kafka events and time ticker. This check, even when there are no messages, causes your CPU to be consumed at a high rate. This behavior is known as busy waiting, where your code is essentially in an active spin-wait state, consuming CPU resources.

Comment: @Mahesh thank you for the reply! Do you know how to properly create such a loop? This is a standard usage of the consumer, as I understand

Comment: I am adding very basic [implementation here](https://goplay.tools/snippet/WR9Jo2uhG5B) you might need to update this as per your requirments. The idea is, The confluent-kafka-go library provides an Events channel that is used to receive delivery reports, errors and events. This is a blocking channel, meaning that when you try to read from it and there's no message, it will block and wait until there is one, effectively causing your loop to wait and reducing CPU usage.

Comment: @Mahesh thanks! won't adding an empty default case to the select give the same functionality? if yes, I tried it and it doesn't work as well